# Need to target specific child cell in table using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a horizontally scrolling table in React, however the requirement is that the right column and left column must be fixed and they could be filled with any content.  Styling wise, I already have the part about being fixed and scrolling functional.  However, I need to adjust the padding of the cell next to the first and last cells to make up for the extra space.

```
    componentDidMount () {
        if(this.props.rightFixedCol) {
            console.log('right col should be fixed')
            //Code to find width, and add it to the padding of next cell

        }
        if(this.props.leftFixedCol) {
            console.log('left col should be fixed')
            //Code to find width, and add it to the padding of next cell
        }
    }
```

This makes it easy to handle when they need to be fixed, however, targeting those cells is the hard part.  I can't mess with  the HTML, only the wrapper which contains the React component.  Usually I would just use querySelectorAll, but since that's not an option inside the React component, I'm a bit stumped.

So how do I get the last cell in a row's width within "this" table? and then how do I set the second to last cell's right padding using React?

Comment: You should add a class in your HTML based on `this.props.rightFixedCol` or `this.props.leftFixedCol`. Then let your CSS handle the rest.

Comment: @HubertJarema I have done that for the basic styling, however, I also need the specific width of that particular cell, in order to have it function as needed.  Which is the problem I'm running into.

Comment: Can you calculate it and add inline CSS style when rendering?

Comment: @HubertJarema that's what I'm attempting to do, but unsure how

Comment: Like this: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style